# Filter nested serializer model field (exclude particular field)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am new to `Django` and I am trying to `exclude` a model field in nested serializer.

modals.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comment")
    comment_bdy = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

serializers.py

```
class BlogCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ("id", "comment_body")

class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comment = BlogCommentSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = ("id", "title", "description", "comment",)
```

I am trying to exclude `comment` which have `completed=True` .

I have tried many times like :-

```
class BlogCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(completed=False)
        return super(BlogCommentSerializer, self).to_representation(data)
```

But It showing:

> AttributeError: 'CommentReply' object has no attribute 'filter'

Then I tried using:

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def get_comment(self, instance):
        comment_instance = instance.comment_set.exclude(completed=True)
        return BlogSerializer(comment_instance , many=True).data
```

It also didn't work.

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to exclude comments which are `completed=True`.

Comment: `CommentReply` is a object not a `Queryset` that's why you're receiving *`AttributeError: 'CommentReply' object has no attribute 'filter'

`*

Comment: @AnkitTiwari, Okay, but How do I relate it with `queryset` instead of `object` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this using [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comment = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_comment(self, instance):
        comment_instances = instance.comment.exclude(completed=True)
        return BlogCommentSerializer(comment_instances , many=True).data
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But it is showing `AttributeError: 'Blog' object has no attribute 'comment_set`. Is it relating with `related_name` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use SerializerMethodField, but use query filtering, and then pass the data to the BlogCommentSerializer serializer

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comment = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_comment(self, obj):
        queryset = Comment.objects.
            filter(blog=obj).exclude(blog__completed=True)
        return [BlogCommentSerializer(q).data for q in queryset]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).